# How deep is the visible area of HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to grab some posts from a blog. All went well until I've wanted to get the post creation date. The DOM-tree for it is:

```
div class="stories-feed__container" 
  -> article 
     -> div class="story__main" 
       -> div class="story__footer" 
         -> div class="story__user user" 
           -> div class="user__info-item" 
             -> time datetime="date and time in UTC format".
```

So I wrote the code:

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc = web.Load("https://pikabu.ru/@serhiy1994");
    string postDate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'stories-feed__container')]/article[2]/div[contains(@class, 'story__main')]/div[contains(@class, 'story__footer')]/div[contains(@class, 'story__user user')]/div[contains(@class, 'user__info-item')]/time").GetAttributeValue("datetime", "NULL"); // e.g. for the 2nd article on the page
```

And it returns the `NullReferenceException`.
BUT if you stop at the "div class="story__user user"" level (e.g.,

```
    string postDate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'stories-feed__container')]/article[2]/div[contains(@class, 'story__main')]/div[contains(@class, 'story__footer')]/div[contains(@class, 'story__user user')]").InnerHtml;
```

it works properly and return you the inner HTML-code.
So I think there is something like 'maximum visibility level" for HtmlAgilityPack, and you won't able to manipulate with the deeper markdown.

Am I right or I'm coding something wrong?

The original page code is here: https://pastebin.com/jFC0XD9C

Comment: Do you really need that full path? How many elements would match `//div[contains(@class, 'user__info-item')`?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing there are 44 divs with that class on the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HtmlAgility will scrape the entire website, regardless of how deep you want to go. You can use this to get to the item you are looking for since you **dont** have to provide the entire path.

This will search the entire site and look for the first `<div>` tag that has the class name `user__info-item`. You can also change `SelectSingleNode` to `SelectNodes` if there are multiple tags then loop through them to get the dates.

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc = web.Load("https://pikabu.ru/@serhiy1994");
    var postDate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='user__info-item']/time");
    Console.WriteLine(postDate.InnerText);
```

**Whats wrong with your code?**

Reason the code above you have doesnt work is because there is another div that you are missing, '`<div class="user__info user__info_left">`'.

If you write your code like this, it works.

```
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='story__main']/div[@class='story__footer']/div[@class='story__user user']/div[@class='user__info user__info_left']/div[@class='user__info-item']/time");
    Console.WriteLine(nodes.InnerText);
```

**Another way**

Another way to do it is by searching for a parent div. Once you find the parent tag, search under that tag to find what you are looking for.

```
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='story__user user']");
    foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        // Search within each node using .// notation
        var timeNodes = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='user__info-item']/time");
        Console.WriteLine(timeNodes.InnerText);
    }
```

[Tested Code here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6uLd9F)

Comment: thanks God and thank you, it works (via the "NodesCollection" way; the way like "div[@class='user__info-item'][" + (i * 2).ToString() + "]/time" doesn't work, but it's no longer necessary)!

Comment: Glad it sorted you out. !!